# Build is failing for older projects for React-Native iOS XCode Version 12.5

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, build-error, apple-m1

It is very new to me see this problem which started happening recently. Previously my app used to work fine on the iOS simulator by running this command `react-native run-ios`. Now I have done a lot of research and made my app run via XCode. But somehow the metro bundler is not linked when the app runs via XCode.

I tried running the app via `react-native run-ios` and every time I am seeing this error. It is too big to copy paste every error here, but here are some of them:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "Swift._ArrayBuffer._copyContents(initializing: Swift.UnsafeMutableBufferPointer<A>) -> (Swift.IndexingIterator<Swift._ArrayBuffer<A>>, Swift.Int)", referenced from:
      generic specialization <serialized, Swift._ArrayBuffer<Swift.Int8>> of Swift._copyCollectionToContiguousArray<A where A: Swift.Collection>(A) -> Swift.ContiguousArray<A.Element> in libMixpanel-swift.a(AutomaticProperties.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)


** BUILD FAILED **


The following build commands failed:
        Ld /Users/careerlabsdev/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CareerLabs_Elev8-gxcfanteiuxazegkgwkjkrjxbdmw/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/CareerLabs.app/CareerLabs normal
(1 failure)
```

I have done a lot of things to make it to work. The only success I got here is, `while running the command react-native run-ios, it opens up the metro bundler server`. After that it fails with giving a 1000 lines of error. I picked the error which had some cream part. Some key words to pick from the error:

- ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
- clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
- Did not understand the word **Ld**, which is listed under BUILD FAILED

What I did is as follows:

1. Deleting node_modules, Pods. Cleaning the build from XCode. Running `npm install` and then `cd ios && pod install` and then ran the command `react-native run-ios`
2. Deleting Pods, Podfile.lock. Did `pod install` and then in the root `react-native run-ios`
3. Doing these:

```
rm -rf ~/Library/Caches/CocoaPods
rm -rf Pods
rm -rf ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/*
pod deintegrate
pod setup
pod install
cd ..
react-native run-ios
```

4. Restarted the system, and ran the command again `react-native run-ios`
5. Added **arm64** in the **Excluded Architecture** from XCode. Please note, this enabled me to  `build and run` the app **successfully** on XCode. But it doesn't get attached to the metro bundler server. Looks like it runs the **release mode** only.
6. Updated my package `react-native-gesture-handler` to the latest one which is **1.10.3**, to see if that removes my problem. But no luck.

My **Podfile** look like this:

```swift
  platform :ios, '10.0'

  use_flipper!({'Flipper' => '0.81.0'})
  post_install do |installer|
    flipper_post_install(installer)
    installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
      target.build_configurations.each do |config|
        config.build_settings.delete 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'
      end
    end
  end
```

I am out of options now, and waiting for some insight to be given. It is indeed frustrating to see an error on something which never created a problem. I am using Apple M1 Chip Macbook.

**Update V1.0**

- I have tried commenting down the `use_flipper!()`, from the `/ios/Podfile`, and then redid the same things, like removing `Pods`, `Podfile.lock`. Running this command, `pod update && pod install && cd.. && npm run ios`. Ran into multiple issues. I don't know what the issue is with XCode and React Native on Apple M1.

**Update V2.0**

I have found some significant places where the developers are complaining about the same. **XCode has forced updated my version to 12.5, without my notice**. And now XCode is creating a problem with RN Older projects. Here are the supportive links for the same:

- [Flipper doesn't build with XCode 12.5 (GitHub)](https://github.com/facebook/folly/issues/1527#issuecomment-788526038)
- [Do I need Flipper? (Reddit)](https://www.reddit.com/r/reactnative/comments/n0vb7b/do_i_need_flipper/)

I hope this may give some insight to the developers who are confused like me. Please take a look, and looks like `Facebook` is fixing it, but don't know when. Have to keep an eye on it :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The one hacky thing which I did to make my app run again like before, is to **downgrade the XCode Version to the previous stable one**, that is **Version 12.4**. I knew about the problem later, because, `XCode` force updated my version which started behaving weird with my already existing project. So the only viable option I saw is to downgrade the version to the previous one, and **everything worked like before**.

**Please Note:** This issue exists majorly with `Apple M1` along with `XCode v12.5` and `BigSur OS`. So go ahead keeping these things in your mind.

For this, I had to do these things:

- Uninstall the `XCode` completely from the Mac. To do that efficiently, considering `XCode` does caches a lot of things on your Mac, use [Mac App Cleaner](https://freemacsoft.net/appcleaner/). If by any chance, you have just removed the **XCode without using the link**, then use this [Completely remove Xcode from Mac](https://dzone.com/articles/how-to-completely-uninstall-xcode-from-mac).
- Install the `XCode` from this resource [XCode Releases](https://xcodereleases.com/). **Please Note:** This is a legit source which takes you directly to the `Apple's download pages`, and no unreliable thing. So you can just go ahead and download the **previous stable version** of the `XCode`, with which **your app was working fine**.
- **Please Note:** Installing the XCode from `App Store` will again install the latest version of the XCode which is buggy `v12.5`. So please don't download and install the same from `Apple Store`. Use the above mentioned source only for best results.
- Install it when the file is downloaded. Make sure you follow this [Setting up development environment React Native](https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup), to avoid any mishaps.
- Run the app again.

Comment: I think downgrading to Xcode would also need to downgrade iOS version in your mobile devices which might be helpful long term so suggest try comment 3 from this thread. This works for me. https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/31179#issuecomment-829536845

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing all third party Pods will need to update their RN Pod Specs to use `XCFrameworks`. That's what I just did and it seems to work ok.

This means that you, as an RN package user, you will either need to wait for the package authors to update their podspecs to use `XCFrameworks` or add a build config that excludes the 'arm64' arch (but then will not work on M1 macs).

Alternatively, you can visit the `node_modules/<package>/thrid-party.podspec` and update it yourself. But that means you will need to build the `XCFrameworks` yourself too. So.....

Comment: It is practically proven that, `XCode` does the force update. So, now I have the version **12.5**, for which the there exists an issue with the `XCode` and `React-Native`. Here are the supportive links: [Flipper Doesn't build with XCode 12.5](https://github.com/facebook/folly/issues/1527#issuecomment-788526038) and [Do I need Flipper](https://www.reddit.com/r/reactnative/comments/n0vb7b/do_i_need_flipper/). **No packaging issue**