# React native, getting error whie building IOS build

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-ios

I'm trying to create IOS build for my app but I'm getting that error. I tried some solutions like changing target , but that didn't worked. Can Someone please tell me why I'm getting that error in IOS

```
Typedef redefinition with different types ('uint8_t' (aka 'unsigned char') vs 'enum clockid_t')
```

[image]
My react native version is 0.64.0

Comment: See this question, I believe, you might get some insights. https://stackoverflow.com/q/67367050/5362583. **Especially V2.0 in the question**